# rspec is not saving to the db a calculated value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I have troubles with one test which I'm writing. I have a Budget model where the promise (column) is been calculated from a Method named `calculate_budget` after a callback `after_create`.

In the normal dev mode the application is saving to the db but in the current test I grepping some other budget records where the promise is 0 instead of the calculated promise.

here some code to

```
before(:each) do
  @member1 = FactoryGirl.create(:member)
  @member2 = FactoryGirl.create(:member, id: "2")
  income = FactoryGirl.create(:income, member: @member1)
  donation1 = FactoryGirl.create(:donation1)
  donation2 = FactoryGirl.create(:donation2)
  @budget = FactoryGirl.create(:budget, donation: donation1, member: @member1)
end

...
..

it "description" do
  receipt1 = Receipt.create!(id: 1, date: '2015-01-01', member: @member1)
  receipt2 = Receipt.create!(id: 2, date: '2015-02-01', member: @member1)
  receipt1.items << ReceiptItem.create!(id: 1, donation_id: 1, amount: 10, receipt_id: 1)
  receipt2.items << ReceiptItem.create!(id: 2, donation_id: 1, amount: 20, receipt_id: 2)

  budget2 = FactoryGirl.create(:budget, title: 'budget2', start_date: '2016-01-01', end_date: '2016-12-31', donation_id: 1, member: @member1)

  ap "#budget promise => #{@budget.title} promise #{@budget.promise} remaining #{@budget.remainingPromiseCurrentBudget}"
  ap "#budget promise => #{budget2.title} promise #{budget2.promise} remaining #{budget2.remainingPromiseCurrentBudget}"

  @budget.save
  budget2.save

  ap Budget.all
  # debugger
  ap "budget2.get_all_old_budgets: #{budget2.get_all_old_budgets}"

  expect(budget2.remainingPromiseCurrentBudget).to be(210)
end
```

#### Any idea why the is not saving the record correctly?

#### update

The records are saved to the test db but just the calculated value of promise it not updated/saved to the test db. as mentioned the dev db is saving the values correctly to the db.

Comment: I can suggest two things: 1. use `save!` in tests - I mean `@budget.save!` and `budget2.save!` 2. Check (and maybe post) your method `remainingPromiseCurrentBudget` - maybe something caches the value. PS I don't see `it` blocks in your code. I hope this is just missed in your post.

Comment: @gotva thx for the answer but it didn't help the `save!` and I have just missed the `it` block

Comment: the `remainingPromiseCurrentBudget` method correct and has no errors

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was in the `before(:each)` block.

I have now added `it'...', skip_before: true do` and copied my initial set-up direct in the test and instead of the `create` methods for the factory girl I have used `build` method and saved it afterwords.

After that the callback has been fired and the promise was saved to the db.

#### *Lesson learned:*

Use build mehtods in the before each block and save it manually in with `.save` instead of using the create block.